# How to split elements inside <p> tag while web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape [url](https://www.bukopin.co.id/page/jaringankantor). However the output is not in the desired format. I need just the Branch name and address. How do I split this information from p tag.

```
    import re

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    page = requests.get(url)
    Branch_list=[]
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
    for i in soup.find_all('div',class_="col-md-9 text-left"):
    
        Branch=i.find_all('p') if i.find_all('p') else '' 
    
        for k in Branch:
    
            k=re.sub(r'<(.*?)>','', str(k))
            
            Branch_list.append(k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.bukopin.co.id/page/jaringankantor")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser').find_all('div', class_="col-md-9 text-left")
paragraphs = [re.sub(r"Tel.+", "", p.find("p").getText(strip=True)) for p in soup]

for paragraph in paragraphs:
    print(paragraph)
```

Output:

```
KCP Rasuna SaidGd. Kementerian Koperasi & UKM, Lt. 1. Jl. HR. Rasuna Said Kav. 3 - 5, Jakarta Selatan 12940
KCP Plaza AsiaJl. Jend. Sudirman Kav. 59 No. 77 Lt. GF No. GF - D Blok A Senayan, Kebayoran Baru, Jakarta Selatan
KCP Bulog IIGedung Diklat Bulog II Jl. Kuningan Timur Blok M2 No.5 Jakarta Selatan 12950
KCP Pondok Indah Plaza VPlaza V Pondok Indah Kav.A11 Jl. Marga Guna Raya - Pondok Indah Jakarta Selatan
KCP Kebayoran LamaJl. Raya Kebayoran Lama No.10 Jakarta Selatan 12220
KCP Kebayoran BaruJl. RS. Fatmawati No.7 Blok A Kebayoran Baru Jakarta Selatan12140
KCP MelawaiJl. Melawai Raya Kebayoran Baru No. 66 Jakarta Selatan 12160
KK PLN Lenteng AgungJl. Raya Tanjung Barat No. 55 Jakarta Selatan 12610
and so on...
```

EDIT: To get this into a `pandas dataframe` try this:

```
import re

import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.bukopin.co.id/page/jaringankantor")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser').find_all('div', class_="col-md-9 text-left")

data = []
for div in soup:
    branch = div.find("strong").getText()
    address = div.find("p").getText(strip=True)
    data.append([branch, re.sub(r"Telp.+", "", address[len(branch):])])

print(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Branch", "Address"]))
```

Output:

```
                                               Branch                                            Address
0                                     KCP Rasuna Said  Gd. Kementerian Koperasi & UKM, Lt. 1. Jl. HR....
1                                      KCP Plaza Asia  Jl. Jend. Sudirman Kav. 59 No. 77 Lt. GF No. G...
2                                        KCP Bulog II  Gedung Diklat Bulog II Jl. Kuningan Timur Blok...
3                            KCP Pondok Indah Plaza V  Plaza V Pondok Indah Kav.A11 Jl. Marga Guna Ra...
4                                  KCP Kebayoran Lama  Jl. Raya Kebayoran Lama No.10 Jakarta Selatan ...
5                                  KCP Kebayoran Baru  Jl. RS. Fatmawati No.7 Blok A Kebayoran Baru J...
...
```

Comment: Hi, Can I split the Branch name and address into two different columns and obtain the final thing in the form of a dataframe?

Comment: Sure you can but first you'd have to come up with a way of splitting the branch name and the address.

Comment: The branch name and address are within two different p tags. Can you suggest how they can be split so that the first p tag(branch name) goes into one list and the next p tag(address) into another?